# What to do when "Unable to locate package" in Debian

Tags: installation, debian

Specifically - I am trying to install gazebo5, which is in the SID list of Debian packages, but command

```
apt-get install gazebo5
```

gives this error:

```
unable to locate package.
```

What should I do? I have connection to the web, I am running it from a virtual machine. I am running terminal as root. What else can I check or trace to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, in Debian, [the `gazebo5` package is available *only* in *Sid*](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gazebo5&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (at version 5.0.1+dfsg-1).

You are most likely *not* running Debian Sid, because [Sid is extremely prone to breakage](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/) and is usually used by developers who like to live on the edge of danger. As the Debian team puts it, from the linked page:

> Please note that security updates for "*unstable*" distribution are **not** managed by the security team. Hence, "*unstable*" does **not** get security updates in a timely manner. For more information please see the [Security Team's FAQ](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#testing).
>
> "*sid*" is subject to massive changes and in-place library updates. This can result in a very "*unstable*" system which contains packages that cannot be installed due to missing libraries, dependencies that cannot be fulfilled etc. Use it at your own risk!

There are a few obvious options available to you:

- You can download the specific precompiled `.deb` files needed by starting [at the package page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gazebo5) and scrolling down to the bottom. Note that you will need to resolve any dependencies on your own. You can then use `dpkg -i FILENAME` to install the .debs in turn. (This is effectively what `apt-get install` and friends automate for you.) There is no guarantee that this will work out of the box, as the precompiled .debs may have dependencies that are not satisfiable on your system, but [backporting from source](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation) may be practical.
- You can ["pin" the specific package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107865/2465) from the specific suite (telling apt that you want to get `gazebo5` from `sid` rather than from your normal suite). This is highly likely to bring in numerous dependencies from *Sid* that you do not want, so at the very least, be *very* careful.
- You can upgrade your system to *Sid*. I really don't recommend this approach, but [here is a brief guide on how to upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80500/2465). Make sure to read the material available and understand what you are doing before you move to Sid; it is quite possible that you won't easily be able to downgrade back to unstable or stable once you take the plunge.
- You can wait until the package you are interested in makes its way into a Debian release. Since [Jessie is just out](https://www.debian.org/News/2015/20150426), and Debian is quite conservative about adding things to released versions, this probably means [keeping an eye out in Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&searchon=names&keywords=gazebo5). *Stretch* seems likely to be released (as Debian 9) somewhere in the first half of 2017 or so, if it follows the same [release cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_GNU/Linux#Release_timeline) as recent Debian versions (about two years interval between major releases).
- You can migrate to a different distribution that does package the software you need. (This is well outside of the scope of your question, but it *is* a possibility.)